# Showing $\frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2}$ is continuous at all points

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The function in the title is also defined to be 0 at (0,0).  So the functon is obviously continuous at all points except (0,0), so I need to show that the limit of the function as (x,y) goes to (0,0) is 0.  I used inequalities, so what I did is

$0\le \frac{x^3y}{x^4+y^2} \le \frac{(x^4+y^2)x}{2(x^4+y^2)}=\frac{x}{2}=0$

where this is as (x,y) goes to (0,0).  My issue is that the above doesn't hold if x and y are different signs, because then it's not greater than 0.  Any way to fix this?  Thanks

Comment: Why is $x^3 y < (x^4 +y^2)x/2$? This is not true for all $x$ and $y$.

Comment: $(x^2-y)^2\ge 0$ so $x^4-2x^2y+y^2\ge 0$ then $x^4+y^2\ge 2x^2y$ and then divide both sides by 2, and I factored out one x initially because that's comstant from both sides

Comment: If $x$ is negative, then dividing by $x$ flips the inequality.

Comment: Which is what I stated is my problem in the question which could be fixed by using absolute value signs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument is essentially correct, just use a technical tip to work with absolute values:

$$\frac{|x^3y|}{2(x^4+y^2)} \leq \frac{|(x^4+y^2)x|}{2(x^4+y^2)}.$$

Comment: Can you provide some help as to how to prove this inequality?

Answer (score 2):

Try using polar coordinates
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
x = r \cos(\theta)\\
y = r \sin(\theta)
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

Then your function becomes
\begin{equation*}
\frac{r^4 \cos^3(\theta) \sin(\theta)}{r^4 \cos^4(\theta) + r^2 \sin(\theta)} = r^2 \frac{\cos^3(\theta)\sin(\theta)}{r^2 \cos^4(\theta)+\sin(\theta)}
\end{equation*}

which you can prove it tends to $0$ when $r \rightarrow 0$, whenever angle $\theta$ you pick (good exercise).